# Fading elements in / out with animations based on the current state

Tags: html, css, reactjs, css-transitions, css-transforms

I have an element that I want to show/hide based on a boolean state, but I also want it to do it using transitions. Check the following example:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false)
    return (
        <div>
            <button onClick={() => {setVisible(!visible)}}> Show/HIde </button>
            <div className={visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}> I'm a div  </div>
        </div>
    );
}

ReactDOM.render(
    <App />,
    document.getElementById("root")
);
```

```css
.hidden,
.visible {
    border: 2px solid black;
    display: inline;
}

.hidden {
    animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    opacity: 0;
  height: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 0px;
}
.visible {
    opacity: 1;
    animation-name: fadeOutOpacity;
    animation-duration: 1s;
}

@keyframes fadeOutOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 0;
        scale: 0.8;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 1;
        scale: 1;
    }
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
    0% {
        opacity: 1;
        scale: 1;
    }
    100% {
        opacity: 0;
        scale: 0.8;
    }
}
```

```html
<div id="root"></div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

I have a few problems with it: it appears on the page load/refresh and then does the animation. Also, when it's invisible, the div still exists. It only has opacity set to zero. So there is a potential risk of it interacting with other elements. For example, when you hover over the space next to the button, the cursor changes because it hovers over the text, even though it's invisible.

Ideally, I want it to disappear entirely or move off the screen. The element will have a position: fixed in my project.

What is the best practice for dealing with a scenario like this? Can I have a snippet, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to fix it with the following code:

```js
const App = () => {
  const [visible, setVisible] = React.useState(false);
  const divRef = React.useRef(false);

  React.useLayoutEffect(() => {
    divRef.current.className = 'hidden-did-fade-out';
  }, []);

  function onAnimationEnd(e) {
    if (e.animationName === 'fadeOutOpacity') {
      e.target.className = 'hidden-did-fade-out';
    }
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setVisible(!visible);
        }}
      >
        Show/HIde
      </button>
      <div ref={divRef} onAnimationEnd={onAnimationEnd} className={visible ? 'visible' : 'hidden'}>
        I'm a div
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```css
.hidden,
.visible {
  border: 2px solid black;
  display: flex;
  visibility: visible;
}

.hidden {
  animation-name: fadeOutOpacity;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 0;
}

.hidden-did-fade-out {
  display: none;
}

.visible {
  animation-name: fadeInOpacity;
  animation-duration: 1s;
  opacity: 1;
}

@keyframes fadeInOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 0;
    scale: 0.8;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1;
    scale: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes fadeOutOpacity {
  0% {
    opacity: 1;
    scale: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
    scale: 0.8;
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```